# Sync Wordpress Menu into another Wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building an intranet using Wordpress and want to have a global menu which can be used across several Wordpress installations. So i only have to update one menu and it will update all. What would be the best method for doing this?

ive tried 'jquery .load' and this works however, i need the menu to be really synced as the menu has role based access (this is setup using a plugin) all the jquery load does it retrieve all of the menu, but this wont be good for user restriction. the users login is already synced across so i have one login for all installations.

hope im making sense.

thanks

Nick

Comment: Try this: http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/networkwide-menu/

Comment: hi, does this work with separate installations of wordpress? im guessing they have got to be on the same server?

Comment: I think it would be much more rigid if you moved to wordpress multi site in order for this functionality.

Comment: ok will look into this. seem logical to do it this way, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i took Chris advice and made my website a network using multisite feature and used the plugin http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/networkwide-menu/ to link my menus together